# ZXing QRCode Scanner Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, qr-code, zxing

I tried to implement the package ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms

this is my xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:zxing="clr-namespace:ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms;assembly=ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms"
         Title="{Binding Title}">

<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout>
        <Label x:Name="scanResultText" />
        <zxing:ZXingScannerView 
            OnScanResult="ScanViewOnScanResult"/>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

and this my xaml.cs :

```
public partial class QRCodePage : ContentPage
{

    public QRCodePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = new QRCodeViewModel();
    }

    public void ScanViewOnScanResult(Result result)
    {
        Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () =>
        {
            scanResultText.Text = result.Text;
        });
    }
}
```

On my device i visualize the fragment but it seems not scanning

Comment: Did you prompt for and allow camera access?

Comment: I write this inside my onCreate method of MainActivity to try with Android
`Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(Application);`
`ZXing.Net.Mobile.Forms.Android.Platform.Init();`
and
Also notice that OnRequestPermissionsResult during execution granResults return 0

Comment: You can try this sample: https://github.com/himanshudwd765/XFQRCodeScanSample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code (`IsScanning="True"`) to your xaml:

```
<StackLayout>
    <Label x:Name="scanResultText" />
    <zxing:ZXingScannerView IsScanning="True"
        OnScanResult="ScanViewOnScanResult"/>
</StackLayout>
```